# Requesting a token using the authorization_code Grant Type

Tags: asp.net, .net-core, oauth-2.0, identityserver4, openid-connect

I want to Request a token using the authorization_code Grant Type, I see it here: https://identitymodel.readthedocs.io/en/latest/client/token.html#

```
var response = await client.RequestAuthorizationCodeTokenAsync(new AuthorizationCodeTokenRequest
{
    Address = IdentityServerPipeline.TokenEndpoint,

    ClientId = "client",
    ClientSecret = "secret",

    Code = code,
    RedirectUri = "https://app.com/callback",

    // optional PKCE parameter
    CodeVerifier = "xyz"
});
```

But I don't know where `code` and `CodeVerifier` is getten.

Comment: have you take a look at the sample provided by Identityserver4? They have provide really good example on how to do it  https://github.com/IdentityServer/IdentityServer4/tree/master/samples/Quickstarts

Comment: @FirdausKamaruddin it uses `RequestClientCredentialsTokenAsync` not `RequestAuthorizationCodeTokenAsync` for me.

Answer (score 0):

As already you know, [Authorization Code Grant](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6749#section-4.1) contains a few steps which you need to read them from [RFC 6749 - The OAuth2.0 Authorization Framework](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6749).

> the authorization
> server redirects the user-agent back to the client using the
> redirection URI provided earlier (in the request or during
> client registration).  The redirection URI includes an
> authorization code and any local state provided by the client
> earlier.

There is a flow diagram in the RFC document which help you figure out how you'll earn the *code*.

In summary:
Your client should send Authorization Code with it's request, then you send the *Code* to the Authorization Server and check it's validity.